# Color three worst performing categories in a bar chart power bi

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, dax

I would like to display the three worst performing sub-categories by sales in a bar chart with a different color. This is the dasboard I'm currently working on, you can get a sample of the Data here [Sales Superstore Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn7Xw.png).
Any ideas for a measure? Thanks in advance

edit: I solved it with following measure:

```
Top N = 
IF
    (SELECTEDVALUE(
        superstore[Sub-Category])
        IN TOPN ( 
            3, 
            FILTER(
                ALLSELECTED(
                    superstore[Sub-Category]),
                    CALCULATE(
                        SUM(
                            superstore[Sales]))>0),
            CALCULATE(SUM(superstore[Sales])),
            ASC),
    "#FD625E",
    "#01B8AA"
)
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I googled.

Comment: I mentioned that because there are a lot of similar cases. Try to change `ALL` to `ALLSELECTED`.

Comment: ```ALLSELECTED``` does not work unfortunately

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `TOPN` expression. `TOPN` is an iterator so in your example you are iterating over `ALL(sub-category)` which is a temporary table in that case. I'll try to reproduce your case and solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of debugging and here is the final result that work and should work for you either. The reason why the bars are not colored after filtering is that, the table that is generated inside your measure put blank values for non-related sub-categories to current selected filter instead of removing them. The code below is doing exactly that, what it should be. Check it out and let me know if it solved your problem.

```
Highlight Top N = 
VAR topX = 2
VAR value_to_highlight =
    MAXX(
        TOPN (
            topX,
            CALCULATETABLE (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[Category2] ),
                    "@totalValue", CALCULATE ( [Total Value] )
                ),
                ALL( Data[Category2] )
            ),
            [@totalValue], ASC
        ),
        [@totalValue]
    )
VAR result = 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [Total Value] <= value_to_highlight, "red",
        "blue"
    )
RETURN 
    result
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DAX function SWITCH as shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOErC7eaWZ0&ab_channel=RADACAD

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Could you look at my measure. Seems to work, but not if the visual is filtered

Answer (score -1):

I noticed, Conditional formatting not available for bar charts. But we can achieve by alternate way.

1. Put Sales field into LEGENDS & VALUES of bar chart.
2. Go to the visualizations pane & open Visual>>Columns
3. Column colors list are in ascending order of sales value.
4. First three colors are worst sale, color accordingly & apply any one color in rest of the columns.
5. Your desired bar graph is ready.

Hope it will resolve your query.[Please refer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIRut.png)

Comment: I believe he wants a dynamic solution.